# Error: AttributeError: module 'mosaic' has no attribute 'st_centroid2D'

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, mosaic

Getting an error when trying to run an example given in the Mosaic website: https://databrickslabs.github.io/mosaic/api/spatial-functions.html#st-centroid2d

Code:

```
from mosaic import enable_mosaic
import mosaic as mos
enable_mosaic(spark, dbutils)

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df = spark.createDataFrame([{'wkt': 'POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))'}])
df.select(mos.st_centroid2D('wkt')).show()
```

Result:

```
Error:  AttributeError: module 'mosaic' has no attribute 'st_centroid2D'
```

This is tried on Microsoft Azure Databricks.

Versions: Mosaic - 0.3.9; Databricks Runtime Version - 11.3 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.3.0, Scala 2.12)

Can you please help to fix this issue?

Comment: please add more information about DBR version, Mosaic version, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the documentation that wasn't updated to reflect the change made to remove `st_centroid2D` and `st_centroid3D` functions.  Instead of that function you need to use the `st_centroid` function that will return a WKT object:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([{'wkt': 'POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))'}])
df.select(mos.st_centroid('wkt')).show(truncate=False)
```

will give:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|st_centroid(wkt)                            |
+--------------------------------------------+
|POINT (25.454545454545453 26.96969696969697)|
+--------------------------------------------+
```

Documentation will be corrected soon.